# Sort and keep first but with pattern conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I have a df such as

```
COL1  COL2         VALUE
SP1_1 AJZ7312.1    22
SP1_1 YP_00321331  33
SP1_1 YP_00321332  89
SP2_1 NP_8821      89
SP2_3 KJZ73167.1   90
SP3_1 AJZ7313.1    10
SP3_1 AJZ7312.1    40
SP4_1 YP_00321332  20 
SP4_1 YP_00321334  10
```

So basicaly I would like to keep for each `COL1`  the lowest `VALUE` **BUT** if the lowest `VALUE` in `COL2` contains no "`_`" pattern, and `IF` there is other values with a "`_`" then I keep that one.

For instance in :

```
COL1  COL2         VALUE
SP1_1 AJZ7312.1    22
SP1_1 YP_00321331  33
SP1_1 YP_00321332  89
```

here the lowest one is : `AJZ7312.1` but it does not contain any "`_`" and `YP_00321331` do contain one and is the second lowest, so I keep that one.

another exemple :

```
COL1  COL2         VALUE
SP3_1 AJZ7313.1    10
SP3_1 AJZ7312.1    40
```

here there is only `COL2` content without "`_`" pattern, so I keep the lowest one : `AJZ7313.1`

Then the expected output for all COL1 should be :

```
COL1  COL2         VALUE
SP1_1 YP_00321331  33
SP2_1 NP_8821      89
SP2_3 KJZ73167.1   90
SP3_1 AJZ7313.1    10
SP4_1 YP_00321334  10
```

So far I know how to sort column and keep the first one (with lowest values)

```
tab=tab.sort_values(by=['VALUE'], ascending = True)
tab=tab.drop_duplicates(subset='COL1', keep="first")
```

but I do not know how to take into accoutn the fast that priority is given to `COL2` values with a "`_`" pattern...

Comment: I edited the expected output sorry, ```SP3_1:AJZ7313.1``` is kept because it has 10 and ```AJZ7312.1``` is higher (40).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using sort and `drop_duplicates`, in a couple of steps for clarity:

```
df["has_underscore"] = np.where(df.COL2.str.contains("_"),  1, 2)
df = df.sort_values(["has_underscore", "VALUE"])
res = df.drop_duplicates(subset = "COL1", keep="first")
```

The output is:

```
    COL1         COL2  VALUE  has_underscore
8  SP4_1  YP_00321334     10               1
1  SP1_1  YP_00321331     33               1
3  SP2_1      NP_8821     89               1
5  SP3_1    AJZ7313.1     10               2
4  SP2_3   KJZ73167.1     90               2
```